# Xamarin emulation over TCPIP

Tags: windows, xamarin, tcp, emulation

## Context

I have two machines.
The first machine is an AMD PC (32GB), running Windows 10 Pro, Visual Studio 2019 and this machine is my development environment. An observation. This processor is very old (12 years), and it do not accepts any emulator ou vm software, cause the processor is very old, and it do not has some instructions needed to run those sws.
The second machine is an Intel notebook (8GB), running Windows 10 Pro, and a VMWare used to run MacOS Catalina, used to build my .ipa iOS packages.

## Need

Cause my AMD machine do not runs any emulator, I cant test my app in all Android versions, that is necessary to garantee its compatibility. So, my main focus is to be able to emulate my app, using Android 7 and 8 emulators. I have an Android device running Android 9, which is the only one I can use to make all my tests.

## Problem

As I cant run any Android emulator in my main machine (AMD), I would like to know if it is possible to execute an emulator in my notebook, and through the network, in my Visual Studio, see this emulator appearing in my Visual Studio device list.
So, debug my project running the code in AMD machine, and emulating in Intel machine.

I do something similar with iOS, cause my Visual Studio debug with iPhone emulators running on my MacOS inside my VMWare.

So, I´d like to do the same thing, but with Android.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: @Cheesebaron This link shows only examples where is a phisical device connected.. but in my situation, I need to emulate over tcpip with an Android emulator Android 7, running on Intel notebook, from my Amd desktop, running Visual Studio in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the computers are on the same network and the Emulator is running on the Laptop and it allows incoming connections. Then you should be able from your AMD machine to run:

```
adb connect ip-of-emulator:port-of-emulator
```

Comment: Yes, both computers are on the same network and Emulator is running on the laptop. But I dont know if it configured to receive incoming connections.. How can I see it ? And, may you say, what are the steps I need to do in both sides ? I am trying to do this steps but it is not working. https://hasper.info/remote-android-emulator/